# Increment date in Google Script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, increment

I want simply to increment a given date in Cell A1 by 1 day. I need two seperat variables, one for the given date and one variable for the new, incremented date. The problem is, that my code always change both variables and I dont know why.

```
function testDate() {

var sht_test = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test');
var date_given = sht_test.getRange(1,1).getValue(); // type a Date in cell A1
var date_new;

date_new = date_given;
date_new = new Date(date_new.setDate(date_new.getDate() +1 ));  

sht_test.getRange(2,1).setValue(date_new);
sht_test.getRange(2,2).setValue(date_given);

}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue / Explanation:

In this part of your code:

`date_new = date_given;`

you pass a **reference** of `date_given` to `date_new`.

Namely, whatever changes you make on `date_new`  are automatically applied to `date_given` since they refer to the **same** date object.

When you increment the date by 1:

`date_new = new Date(date_new.setDate(date_new.getDate() +1 ));`

the part: `date_new.setDate(date_new.getDate() +1 )`

increments (changes) `date_new` and therefore `date_given` is also modified since they both refer the the same object.

This is why `date_new` and `date_given` return the same value.

In order to separate them, you need to create a copy of `date_given` which will be a new date object:

`date_new = new Date(date_given);`

and therefore if you later modify `date_new`, `date_given` won't be modified.

---

### Solution:

```
function testDate() {

var sht_test = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test');
var date_given = sht_test.getRange(1,1).getValue(); // type a Date in cell A1
var date_new;

date_new = new Date(date_given);
date_new = new Date(date_new.setDate(date_new.getDate() +1 ));  

sht_test.getRange(2,1).setValue(date_new);
sht_test.getRange(2,2).setValue(date_given);

}
```

Comment: this makes sense! Thank you very much!